# Stable Law for products of random matrices?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, random-matrix

Product of random variables tends to converge to Log-Normal distribution, is there a similar law for a product of large invariant random matrices?

Following Burda [survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.2568), Section V, multiplying such matrices corresponds to multiplying their S-Transforms. What does the limiting distribution look like?

If we have a large matrix $X_i$ with IID standard normal entries and $Y_k=X_1\ldots X_k$, S-transform of $Z=Y_k Y_k^T$ appears to be $1/(1+z)^k$, wondering if large $k$ limit has a name.

**Edit** cross-[posted](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/451732/what-does-a-product-of-many-gaussian-matrices-converge-to) to mathoverflow, numerical simulations suggest limiting density is somewhat invariant to distribution of matrix entries (tried products of Gaussian matrices and matrices with uniform entries)

[image]